# Buildroot - building ISO image

Tags: linux-kernel, x86, cross-compiling, buildroot

Firs, please excuse me - those are my first steps in building OS and using Buildroot.

I've managed to create my first custom os (nothing special, just a first test with patched 4.6.3 kernel with grsec).

I have this files in /output/images dir:

```
$ ls -lh
total 304M
-rw-r--r-- 1 fugitive fugitive  512 Apr 13 01:01 boot.img
-rw-r--r-- 1 fugitive fugitive 4.1M Apr 13 00:57 bzImage
-rw-r--r-- 1 fugitive fugitive  79M Apr 13 01:01 disk.img
-rw-r--r-- 1 fugitive fugitive 137K Apr 13 00:57 grub-eltorito.img
-rw-r--r-- 1 fugitive fugitive 137K Apr 13 00:57 grub.img
-rw-r--r-- 1 fugitive fugitive  69M Apr 13 01:01 rootfs.cpio
-rw-r--r-- 1 fugitive fugitive  79M Apr 13 02:10 rootfs.ext2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 fugitive fugitive   11 Apr 13 01:01 rootfs.ext4 -> rootfs.ext2
-rw-r--r-- 1 fugitive fugitive  74M Apr 13 01:01 rootfs.iso9660
```

What my goal is - to create a bootabile iso image, but I don't know how.

I am able to emulate it with qemu, like you can see on the screenshot:

[image]

I've tried to burn `rootfs.iso9660` to USB drive, but not able to boot.

Tried to rename rootfs.iso9660 to rootfs.iso9660.iso and try with VirtualBox, but then I got a grub terminal.

Appreciate the help and instructions!

**EDIT:**

.config file:

```
-bash-4.2$ grep  BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_ .config | grep -v ^#
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_CPIO=y
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_CPIO_NONE=y
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2=y
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_4=y
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_GEN=4
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_REV=1
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_LABEL=""
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_BLOCKS=0
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_INODES=0
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_EXTRA_BLOCKS=0
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_EXTRA_INODES=0
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_RESBLKS=0
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_NONE=y
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_ISO9660=y
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_ISO9660_GRUB2=y
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_ISO9660_BOOT_MENU="fs/iso9660/grub.cfg"
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_ISO9660_INITRD=y

-bash-4.2$ grep -r BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_ISO9660_HYBRID *
fs/iso9660/Config.in:config BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_ISO9660_HYBRID
fs/iso9660/iso9660.mk:ifeq ($(BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_ISO9660_HYBRID),y)
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you enabled `BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_ISO9660_HYBRID` ? This is needed if you want your ISO image to also work from a USB device.

Comment: Please see the updated question, I've enabled in `make menuconfig` step ISO target as well. Let me know if you need something else!

Comment: Thomas : Seems not.. I am not sure how to enable it, as I don't see it in something similar in menuconfig, and not sure about dependencies for it..

Comment: @fugitive: you have to choose isolinux instead of grub2, then the isohybrid option appears. It's not very transparent, I know, but it's hard to change due to limitations of Kconfig.

Comment: @Arnout Found it. I'll try a let you guys know. Thank you for tips!

Comment: @fugitive Can you post your solution here (as an answer to your own question)?

Comment: @Arnout Sorry, I simply didn't manage to get it work. Even with switching to isolinux. Unable to boot, only could run via qemu. So I gave up. But, I've created a tons of different images for Raspberry so far, different kernels, different compilers etc, and they all worked out of the box

Comment: Uh, are you building for Raspberry? Raspberry cannot boot from CD or isohybrid USB...

Answer (score 2):

A bootable ISO image (old school ISO just for CDROMs) with Grub2 - I made it work.

### The main hints:

- Grub: add builtin modules `biosdisk iso9660`
- Grub: boot partition set to `cd`
- After changing Grub options you need to recompile it (read [how to rebuild package](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#rebuild-pkg) in official manual)
- If you do changes in kernel config, make sure that CDROM devices and ISO9660 filesystem are supported
- If you are in grub rescue console (which is not a good sign), try to execute commands step by step ([like in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/166338/434353)) to figure out the issue.

### Extract from .config

I saved my changes as defconfig (`make savedefconfig`, read [here](https://www.viatech.com/en/2015/06/buildroot/)) and here is what you should have in yours:

```
BR2_ROOTFS_POST_BUILD_SCRIPT="board/pc/post-build.sh"
BR2_ROOTFS_POST_IMAGE_SCRIPT="support/scripts/genimage.sh"
BR2_ROOTFS_POST_SCRIPT_ARGS="-c board/pc/genimage-bios.cfg"
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2=y
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_4=y
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_SIZE="120M"
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_ISO9660=y
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_ISO9660_BOOT_MENU="fs/iso9660/grub.cfg"
BR2_TARGET_GRUB2=y
BR2_TARGET_GRUB2_BOOT_PARTITION="cd"
BR2_TARGET_GRUB2_BUILTIN_MODULES="boot linux ext2 fat squash4 part_msdos part_gpt normal biosdisk iso9660"
BR2_PACKAGE_HOST_GENIMAGE=y
```

Side note: I started my trials with building a default configuration for PC `make pc_x86_64_defconfig && make`

### Test

Test your ISO in QEMU:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 512 -cdrom output/images/rootfs.iso9660
```

It also works in Virtual Box.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/output/images/disk.img of=/path/to/usb/drive bs=1M
```

To know the path to your usb drive do :

```
lsblk
```

and find your usb drive.